# How do I set Bluetooth headphones as the default audio output?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, headphones

My computer is a laptop Dell Inspiron N5110 with built-in Intel Centrino Wireless Bluetooth 3.0 + High Speed Adapter. I want to use my new Bluetooth headphones Sennheiser MM 500-X as default audio output (Windows 7), but I can`t seem to find the way how, since yesterday.

I followed the instructions found somewhere to reinstall the Bluetooth adapter driver, but that only resulted in the inability to connect with headphones whatsoever. Ever since I did that, the headphones do not show up in Windows at all like they don't exist... Yesterday, I could at least have them connected. Now I can't even do that.

Comment: Assuming you are using Windows, have you tried System Restore to a point before yesterday?

Comment: no I haven`t but that`s not the point. I need the headset to be a default audio output. I`m trying Broadcomm BT software now.

Comment: the latest restore point I had was from this morning, I restored it and it didn`t help.

Comment: Okay I handled it!

In the "Bluetooth Settings" window there at "options" tab there I checked "Allow Bluetooth devices connecting with this computer". Afterwards, the headset was available at system audio mixer video!

Answer (score 1):

This link should explain it exactly. 
[configure-bluetooth-headphones-in-laptop](http://mwolk.com/blog/configure-bluetooth-headphones-in-laptop/)

- Just right-click the sound icon,
- click playback devices,
- right-click on the sound device you want to use
- click set as default.

Comment: yeah I knew that even before I had the headphones... They do not appear in that window. Hell, they don`t appear anywhere in the system. I have no problem connecting them to my phone, but to my laptop they are invisible.

Comment: ok did you try adding them again like that link shows?

Comment: Okay I handled it!

In the "Bluetooth Settings" window there at "options" tab there I checked "Allow Bluetooth devices connecting with this computer". Afterwards, the headset was available at system audio mixer video!

Comment: Ok great glad you figured it out